# When push new view to NavigationPath using NavigationStack others views in stack also get called in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationstack

Why this happening, and any solution would be appreciate. I'm using Coordinator pattern where all views pushed in a central place.

Coordinator

```
class Coordinator: ObservableObject {

@Published var path = NavigationPath()

func push(_ page: Page) {path.append(page) }
func pop() {
    guard !path.isEmpty else {return}
    path.removeLast()
}
func popToRoot() {
    guard !path.isEmpty else {return}
    path.removeLast(path.count)
 }
}

extension Coordinator {
@ViewBuilder
func build(page: Page) -> some View {
    switch page {
    case .tenantInfo:
        IntroView()
    case .home:
        Home()
    }
 }
}
```

CoordinatorView

```
struct CoordinatorView: View {

@StateObject private var coordinator = Coordinator()
@State var isLoggedIn = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path) {
        Group {
            if isLoggedIn {
                coordinator.build(page: .home)
            } else {
                coordinator.build(page: .tenantInfo)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationDestination(for: Page.self) { page in
            coordinator.build(page: page)
        }
    }
    .environmentObject(coordinator)
  }
}
```

Root ContentView

```
struct ContentView: App {
 var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        CoordinatorView()
    }
  }
}
```

Page

```
enum Page {
  case tenantInfo
  case home
}
extension Page: Identifiable {
 var id: Self { self }
}
extension Page: Hashable {
 func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(self.hashValue)
 }
 static func == (lhs: Page, rhs: Page) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.tenantInfo, .tenantInfo),
        (.home, .home):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
 }
}

struct IntroView: View {
 var body: some View {
    Text("Intro View")
 }
}
struct Home: View {
 var body: some View {
    Text("Home View")
 }
}
```

this is my app base structure for navigation. if I push one view, using coordinator.push() all the views in navigation path rebuild.

Comment: At least can you share some code?

Comment: strange looking SwiftUI code

Comment: what make this code strange looking, would you please explain. I am new to swiftui